# Is there a code style/ESLint rule for consistent export syntax?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a way to force automatically a specific syntax for exporting modules in JavaScript (either `export` keyword or `export {name}` at the end of the file) ?

I spent few hours in the docs to find it without success... If it doesn't really exist, I could create a custom rule.

I also checked how Google ([source](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#es-module-exports)) address this aspect, but these syntaxes seem to be both allowed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did u try `{
  "rules": {
    "import/export": "error"
  }
}
` ? According to chat gpt that would do, I doubt though.